# How to pass parameters to a Flash Lite 1.1 movie?

Tags: flash, flashlite

How can I pass parameters to a Flash Lite 1.1 movie?

Answer (score 0):

FlashVars is not enabled for the browser using Flash Lite, you should use XML or a name value pair formatted TXT fil etc after the SWF has loaded.

Comment: Yes, but without even a single parameter to bootstrap the loading process that is not too useful. I can load an XML from the server, but I cannot pass any context to the server that is not hard-coded in the movie.

Comment: Depends what the context is that you require... Can you tie it to system time, network speed, Application Device Objects or Services? Maybe your need to get a little creative.